# Error in black background when fixing Landsat 7 scan-line error with ArcGIS pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, landsat-7

I am trying to fix the scan-line error of a Landsat 7 imagery (Fig 1) with the Landsat Toolbox of ArcGIS Pro 3.0. However, there seems some problems when it was processing the black background, as Fig 2 shows.

As Fig 3 shows, I just input a single band image of Landsat 7 data and the output directory, is there any other preprocessing should I do, or should I add a mask?

[image]

[image]

[image]